Raspberry Pi 5 Not detecting NVME SSD over usb 3.0, but detecting on usb 2.0
I'm encountering an issue with my setup involving a Crucial P3 NVMe M.2 SSD in a USB 3.1 Gen2 enclosure connected to my Raspberry Pi's USB 3.0 port.
I am able to read it over USB 2.0 Port (using lsblk).
My current setup is as follows:
Raspberry pi 5 with Pi 5 power supply, using pimoroni nvme base to boot from nvme ssd (again crucial p3 1 TB).
Another SSD is connected using USB 3.0, just to act as an external drive.
I am providing the outputs for the commands below:
pi@pi5:~ $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/firmware
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   931G  0 part /

As you can see above, only one nvme disk is shown (which is the boot disk)
I'm wondering if anyone has experience with this setup and could provide some guidance.
Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!"

Thanks for your response Seamus,

What I see is one NVME device - as expected - with two (2) partitions - again, as expected. This appears to be a perfectly normal setup... at least it's identical to what I see on my RPi5

For the above I have connected two NVME SSDs to my Pi5, one using Pimoroni NVME Base and one USB 3.0.
ISSUE:
SSD when connected to USB 3.0 is not visible, but when the same SSD is connected over USB 2.0, it is visible with lsblk, as you can see below:
pi@pi5:~ $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0 931.5G  0 part /media/devmon/Pi-backup
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/firmware
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   931G  0 part /

For clarification:
I have tested usb 3.0 with a SanDisk thumbdrive, and it reflects back in Pi5 with lsblk

how does this answer your question?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
